# SELECT WHERE IN list with Dapper ORM; exception if NULL check

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

SQL Server with Dapper

```
List<string> valueList = new List<string> { "20230626", "20230808"};
string sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE @Values IS NULL OR Value IN @Values";
var result = connection.Query<dynamic>(sql, new { Values = valueList });
```

> SqlException: an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

If I use this, then it works OK:

```
List<string> valueList = null
```

Without NULL check, it works OK

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Value IN @Values
```

1. Is Dapper rewriting the query when using IN parameter?
2. Is there a workaround that does not use dynamic SQL or table-valued parameters or similar?

Comment: Why can't you use a table valued parameter?

Answer (score 2):

*1. Is Dapper rewriting the query when using IN parameter?*

Yes [that's exactly what it does](https://www.learndapper.com/parameters#dapper-where-in-parameters). This is one of the reasons you should tend to avoid this if you have a large dataset: the maximum number of parameters in SQL Server is 2100, and you would hit performance problems well before that.

*2. Is there a workaround that does not use dynamic SQL or Table Valued params or similar?*

A Table-Valued Parameter would be ideal. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921999/dapper-table-valued-parameter-with-string-query) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73568667/14868997) shows how to use it, it's pretty simple.

Otherwise, you can do the following:

```cs
var valueList = new List<string> { "20230626", "20230808"};
string sql = @"
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE @ValuesEmpty = 1
   OR Value IN @Values;
";

using var result = connection.Query<dynamic>(sql, new { Values = valueList, ValuesEmpty = valueList.Count == 0 });
```

Having said that, it's probably better to build up the query dynamically, in order to get the best query plan. Note that parameters are *still* used, do *not* inject actual data into the query.

This solution can also be used with a TVP.

```cs
var valueList = new List<string> { "20230626", "20230808"};
string sql = @"
SELECT *
FROM MyTable";

if (valueList.Count > 0)
    sql += "
WHERE Value IN @Values;
";

using var result = connection.Query<dynamic>(sql, new { Values = valueList });
```